# ¿Cómo pasar una imagen por parámetros según su dirección?

Tags: java, imagen, ireport

Tengo la dirección de una imagen que se encuentra fuera de la carpeta del proyecto, lo que quiero es pasar esa dirección a mi reporte para poder ver la imagen en mi reporte pero no sé como ponerlo en el parámetro, tengo imágenes que paso pero estas se encuentran en la carpeta del proyecto.

Este es el código donde paso por parámetro a mi reporte:

```
  Map parametro = new HashMap();
        parametro.put("codalmacen", codalmacen);
        parametro.put("codsubalmacen", codsubalmacen);
        parametro.put("tipoguia", tipoguia);
        parametro.put("emiguia", emiguia);
        parametro.put("nroguia", nroguia);
        parametro.put("usuariocrea", dataAsig[0][0]);
        parametro.put("usuarioautoriza", usuarioautoriza);
        parametro.put("usuarioatiende", Logueo.id_personal);
        parametro.put("usuarioasignado", usuariocrea);
        parametro.put("SUBREPORT_CONNECTION", cnp.getConnection());
        parametro.put("SUBREPORT_CONNECTION_PL", cna.getConnection());
        parametro.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "" + getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("m_reportes/"));
        parametro.put("logo", getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("m_imagen/logo.gif"));
        parametro.put("logo2", getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("m_  imagen/logo.gif"));
```

yo quiero pasar esta direccion "D:\Dioses\Erps\copias\PitsErp - copia\temp\016001615.png" he tratado esto

```
 parametro.put("firma", getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("D:\Dioses\Erps\copias\PitsErp - copia\temp\016001615.png"));
```

Pero no me sale ninguna imagen.

pdt: sé que me pueden decir que pase la imagen defrente al reporte y solo le doy la dirección y esta listo, pero esta dirección cambia según la pc donde se corre el programa, por eso no puedo hacer eso y por eso lo hago por parámetros.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En la ruta que estás indicando el carácter separador debería ser una doble barra "\\", y no una barra simple.

Prueba cambiarlo a:

```
 parametro.put("firma", getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("D:\\Dioses\\Erps\\copias\\PitsErp - copia\\temp\\016001615.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu proyecto en la carpeta `resources` crea una carpeta que se llame `imagenes` y ahí agregas tu imagen que quieres mostrar.

Declaras una variable de tipo String en donde ponemos el nombre de la carpeta que creamos y el nombre de tu imagen por ejemplo:

```
String imagen="/imagenes/logo.jpg";
```

y en el `HashMap` le pasamos el parámetro de la siguiente manera:

```
parametro.put("logo", this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagen));
```

De esta forma no importa en que pc corras tu programa.

Answer (score 0):

Usa las clases `Path` y `Paths`

```
Path rutaImagen = Paths.get("D:","Dioses","Erps","copias","PitsErp - copia","temp","016001615.png");
parametro.put("rutaImagen", rutaImagen);
```

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que la clase principal se llama "Main" el código debe ser así:

parametro.put("firma", Main.class.getResourceAsStream("D:\Dioses\Erps\copias\PitsErp - copia\temp\016001615.png"));